# How to automatically compare two aerial photographs with a GIS with regard to certain features?

Tags: qgis, analysis, aerial-photography

At present, we are trying to automatically record the new use of land by buildings by systematically comparing aerial photographs (e.g. 2007 farmland -> 2008 warehouse). For this purpose, high-resolution aerial photographs are available every year since 2000 as WMS service.

Is there a plugin for QGis or ArcGis that could help here? Or is there another tool that you can buy for this purpose? Has anyone done something similar before?

Comment: This is a (challenging) classification problem. First you need to classify the image into useful classes such as buildings, vegetation, water, etc. Then run a change detection analysis. Alternatively, use feature extraction methods that isolate the buildings--then compare. The QGIS suite has a variety of tools to do that. I would begin with the Orfeo toolbox and look into feature extraction.